# Microsoft SQL Server - Tables owner names

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, admin, owner

I have been trying for days to find a command that will return me the owner's name for particular database.
e.g. Database name = WAREHOUSE_DATA (within this database there are 500 tables and multiple owners)

Is there a way to find, somehow, their names or IDs.

The latest one that I tried is:

```
SELECT *
FROM WAREHOUSE_DATA.sys.tables
```

but it doesn't have the names of the table creators.

Note: I am just using MSSMS, I do not have any server tools or something else for monitoring the whole server.

Thanks.

Comment: In SQL Server the creator and the owner are different things. Which are you actually after, as you seem to use the word interchangibly. If you want the former, then unless *you* log this somewhere, then you won't have it (SQL Server doesn't store this information). If you want the owner, this is related to the schema the table is on (and you can easily get the schema by using the `sys.schemas` system view).

Comment: e.g. I have database name = WAREHOUSE_DATA, schema name: PROD and let's say 5 tables:
1. aaa_customers
2. bbb_price
3. ccc_address
4. ddd_revenue
5. eee_cost
Now, I know that I have created table 4, but I would like to see who are the creators for table 1,2,3 and 5 (their first/last name)

Comment: That doesn't answer the question I asked in the comment, @fym . You don't confirm if you want the creator or the owner (schema).

Comment: I do not understand your question, to be the honest. I gave you an example above, so I just interested to see who created a table, under database = WAREHOUSE_DATA, on the SQL server. I am not an expert therefore that could be the reason of misunderstanding your question.

Comment: *"so I just interested to see who created a table*" *This* answers the question I asked: *"[Do] you want the creator or the owner (schema)"*. And the answer is that unless you logged somewhere who did create it, then you're out of luck; SQL Server does not log this information.